# What is the difference between Private app and Public app on BigCommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

Few questions I have as below:

1. Is the procedure for registering, submitting and installing the Public app is same for Private app also?
2. Private app uses Basic Authentication and can only be used by a merchant for his store specific requirements or customizations only. It cannot be used by other merchant, right?
3. How a merchant can create and install Private app on his merchant control panel? How it will get listed on the merchant's store control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the documentation, a private app technically refers to an app that uses basic authentication. It doesn't require registering, submitting, and installing, just the transference of auth credentials. If you wanted to have a "private" app that uses OAuth credentials (anything using OAuth is referred to as a public app in the docs), then you'd need to keep your app in draft status and the process would be the same as you described.
2. A private app could be used by multiple merchants, but it wouldn't be discoverable in the app marketplace. This was our old method for integrating apps and we recommend using OAuth.
3. Basic auth apps cannot be visible in the control panel. Only apps that use OAuth can.

Comment: Thanks Alyss once again. This is what I was looking for and your understanding is absolutely correct. I too confirmed this with the BigCommerce team. :)

Comment: happy to help (and I am the developer advocate at BigCommerce).